# Not well formed xml created using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, character-encoding, export

I created a XML document with Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio using standard commands like:

```
FOR XML AUTO
```

It creates a correct XML file. If I click a preview it shows me well formed XML document, but if I save it, I get not well formed document.

The result looks like:

[image]

Instead of in preview it was something like this:

[image]

The whole file is huge and I can't save it from preview.

Answer (score 0):

This is an encoding problem and not a question of *well formed XML*. SQL Server will not produce invalid XML. The preview is the proof. So:

- How are you writing the file away? (Are you using `BCP`? Try the `-w` option)
- How did you open the file to check its content? The file might be okay, but your tool did not open it correctly.
- Open the file with a mighty editor (like *notepad++*) and check its encoding. Try to change the encoding.

You must ensure to write this as unicode (`utf-16`, `ucs-2`) to your disk.
Any variable you use to store this must be `XML` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`!